# How to compute $E\left[W_t \int_0^t s \, dW_s\right]$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I want to compute $E\left[W_t \int_0^t s \, dW_s\right]$  where $W_t$ is a Brownian motion. My attempt below is based on some very shaky mathematics; in particular I have no justification of the 4th equality but it leads me to the right answer. Can anyone show me the correct way to compute this expectation?

$$ E\left[W_t \int_0^t s \, dW_s\right]
= E\left[\int_0^t dW_s \int_0^t s \, dW_s\right]
= E\left[\int_0^t \int_0^t s \, dW_s \, dW_s\right]
= E\left[\int_0^t s \, dt\right]=\frac{t^2}{2}
$$

Comment: The equality between the second and third terms is also bogus because you've conflated the two dummy variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: The expression $E\left[\int_0^t dW_s \int_0^t s\,dW_s\right]$ looks helpful.  Now recall the Itô isometry.

Hint 2: If you only know the Itô isometry in the form $E\left[\left(\int_0^t A_s\,dB_s\right)^2\right] = E\left[\int_0^t A_s^2\,ds\right]$, then think about the simple identity $ab = \frac{(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2}{4}$.  (Or the magic word "polarization".)  Or, stated in a more sophisticated way, a linear map between Hilbert spaces that preserves the (squared) norm also preserves the inner product.

Comment: If the integrand $s$ was not in the second integral, I would be able to apply Itô's isometry. But I'm not sure what to do as things stand

Comment: @aukie: Ok, I added another hint.

Comment: Thanks, the second hint did the trick. Was not aware of other forms of Itô's isometry